# How do I prevent a long press in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a HTML5 game. When the user presses this key (let's say z) the character attacks. However, currently in my code, the user can just hold z so that the character will attack indefinitely.

I need to implement a code that will prevent this "long-press" from happening. In other words, if the user keeps holding z, the character will eventually stop attacking so the user will have to keep tapping z instead of just holding the key down.

Comment: use `keyup` instead?

Comment: you can use `keydown`  so in this case user will have to press the key again and again

Comment: Please show your current code on how you are capturing the key press event. Better still provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a flag that will only fire once unless reset.

```
var pressed = false;
window.addEventListener("keydown", ()=>{
  if(!pressed){
   pressed = true;
   //Do thing
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
 pressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using the `keypress` or `keydown` events, try using `keyup` instead.